# Applying dot product to list of vectors

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have:
`w = {1,0}`. I want to apply the dot product of `w` to each element of the list of vectors `x = {{1,2}, {3,4}, {4,5}}` to get `{1,3,4}`. Simply doing `w.x` does not work. How do I do this?

Comment: try `x.w` and it works

Comment: `Map[Dot[w, #] &, x]`

Answer (score 3):

As J42161217 already wrote in a comment, you may use `x.w` in this case.

Should you ever have to compute the entrywise `Dot`-products of *two* lists of vectors `x` and `y` of same size, you may use the undocumented function `` NDSolve`FEM`MapThreadDot ``:

```
n = 1000000;
x = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2}];
y = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2}];

a = MapThread[Dot, {x, y}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
b = NDSolve`FEM`MapThreadDot[x, y]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

Max[Abs[a - b]]
```

> 0.722634
>
> 0.01565
>
> 0.

Unfortunately, this works only for vectors of *machine precision reals*.